# Which is better: "go ahead..." or "proceed..." quite well

Tags: phrase-choice

Which is better?

> I'll work on it 4 hours per day so project should **proceed** quite well.
>
> I'll work on it 4 hours per day so project should **go ahead** quite well.

Comment: *proceed* is probably clearer but neither is wrong. But minor correction -  "I'll work on it 4 hours per day, so *the* project should proceed/go ahead quite well." I would use the comma to separate the action from the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add "the" ("...so *the* project should..."). Secondly, user3169 is correct that you can use them interchangeably. "Go ahead" is more colloquial whereas "proceed" is more formal.